# What would a schema look like for setting up tables for RPG character creation restrictions?

Tags: schema

I'm trying to figure out how to layout tables for an RPG database where information such as character race, class, and deity have restrictions on what combination is permissible.

For example:

```
Race
-----------
id | name
1  | Human
2  | Elf
3  | Dwarf

Class
-----------
id | name
1  | Warrior
2  | Wizard
3  | Thief

Deity
-----------
id | name
1  | GodA
2  | GodB
3  | GodC
```

I want to limit certain combinations such as only humans and elves can be wizards, only humans and dwarves can be warriors, but all three can be thieves. But I also want to restrict the deity to certain race/class combinations. For example, humans can only worship GodA or GodB but NOT GodC; choosing to be a thief means you can't worship GodB so you end up only being able to choose GodA, etc.

What kind of schema can be used to map this information, is there a name for this type of relational data, and what would a query look like to retrieve the final mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fairly standard modeling exercise, all you are doing is laying out the relationships that will provide valid selections for each character (and as a benefit populate drop-down menus on the front end).

Based on your descriptions, we have the following dependencies:

```
Race -> Class
Race -> Deity
Class -> Deity
```

So we will need three entities, `RaceClass`, `RaceDeity`, and `ClassDeity`.  The primary key will be a composite of the primary key of each parent entity.

The `Character` entity will have a FK relationship to those three entities to ensure the values for `Race`, `Class`, and `Deity` are valid.

In diagram form:
[image]

A few notes:

For tables with a limited number of values (often with common/easily understood abbreviations), it makes sense to use a short character value for the primary key instead of an auto-incrementing integer.  This provides us with a few advantages:

1. Easier to program, simpler queries, no need to join back to reference tables with values that are easily understood. `(1, 'Jim the Somewhat Strong','HUM','WAR','GODA')` versus `(1, 'Jim the Somewhat Strong', 2, 3, 1)`.
2. Less chance of mistakes as there is no overlap in key values, e.g. `1` could mean Thief or Elf or GodB, transpositions are impossible/very unlikely with a human readable codes.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a specific schema name for what you're trying to achieve but there are two ways you can go about achieving it depending on which database management system you end up using.

1. You can create one linking table for each combination of values. Every *legal* combination will get it's own row, and have a foreign key field of the `id` of each base table that it's linking together. This is generally known as a **dimension combination** table.
2. You can alternatively look into having a more denormalized table that stores each instance of the `character` that's been selected, with foreign key refencing fields to each `id` of the base tables, with a **composite constraint** on what value combinations can be entered in each field. (The availability of this kind of complex **constraint** feature will be dependent on the database system you use.)